# JavaFX proper use of stages and stage controllers (bad start)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, scene

I have spent the last couple of days looking into this and trying my hand at some different solutions found but Im still having a hard time implementing them correctly.

I have a project that's bound to turn into something mid-sized so I want to make sure I am using MVC correctly from the start instead of just hacking it apart "making it work".

As of now the application will only open 3 scenes, 2 on start(no fxml needed) and another for settings(using a FXML). I do need to be careful of strong references to these as this application will be running on low resource devices.

Ultimately my questions are:
Am I using scenes and controllers correctly? and given the way I have initiated the settings scene Im not finding a way to edit it with a controller. What am I doing wrong?

Below is what I have so far and I must say I dont like the way I initialize the first 2 scenes from Main and of course trying to start the settings scene is rather haphazard. My hurdle now is trying to interact with the scenes through their controllers.

**Main.java**

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.controllers.StageController;

<pre>
public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        StageController newStage = new StageController();
        newStage.start(primaryStage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**StageController.java**

```
package sample.controllers;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import java.util.List;

import static sample.controllers.HotkeyController.createHotkeys;
import static sample.controllers.WebViewController.createWebView;

/**
 * Created by devin on 4/14/16.
 */
public class StageController extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception
    {
        Screen primaryScreen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Screen secondaryScreen;
        List<Screen> allScreens = Screen.getScreens();
        if (allScreens.size() <= 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Only one screen");
            secondaryScreen = primaryScreen;
        }
        else
        {
            if (allScreens.get(0).equals(primaryScreen))
            {
                secondaryScreen = allScreens.get(1);
            }
            else
            {
                secondaryScreen = allScreens.get(0);
            }
        }
        configureStage("Primary", primaryStage, primaryScreen);
        final Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
        configureStage("Secondary", secondaryStage, secondaryScreen);
    }
    private void configureStage(final String name, final Stage stage, final Screen screen)
    {
        Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getBounds();
        System.out.println(name + ":" + bounds);

        stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
        stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        showStage(name, stage, screen);

        stage.show();
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
    }

    private void showStage(final String name, final Stage stage, final Screen screen)
    {
        //Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        createWebView(name, root);
        scene.setRoot(root);

        /*
         * Use hotkeys to allow application actions
         */
        createHotkeys(name, scene);
    }

}
```

**WebViewController**

```
package sample.controllers;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

/**
 * Created by devin on 4/13/16.
 */
public class WebViewController
{

    public static void createWebView(final String name, final StackPane root)
    {
        final WebView browser = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        if (name == "Primary") {
            webEngine.load("http://google.com");
        }
        else
        {
            webEngine.load("http://google.com");
        }

        webEngine.documentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Document>()
        {
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> prop, Document oldDoc, Document newDoc)
            {
                String heightText = browser.getEngine().executeScript(
                        "window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('height')"
                ).toString();
                double height = Double.valueOf(heightText.replace("px", ""));

                System.out.println("Height of browser on " + name + " " + height);
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(browser);

        /* This is a firebug call if we need to debug the webpage that is being loaded */
//        webEngine.documentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Document>() {
//            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> prop, Document oldDoc, Document newDoc) {
//                enableFirebug(webEngine);
//            }
//        });
    }

    private static void enableFirebug(final WebEngine engine) {
        engine.executeScript("if (!document.getElementById('FirebugLite')){E = document['createElement' + 'NS'] && document.documentElement.namespaceURI;E = E ? document['createElement' + 'NS'](E, 'script') : document['createElement']('script');E['setAttribute']('id', 'FirebugLite');E['setAttribute']('src', 'https://getfirebug.com/' + 'firebug-lite.js' + '#startOpened');E['setAttribute']('FirebugLite', '4');(document['getElementsByTagName']('head')[0] || document['getElementsByTagName']('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E = new Image;E['setAttribute']('src', 'https://getfirebug.com/' + '#startOpened');}");
    }

}
```

**HotkeyController.java**

```
package sample.controllers;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Created by devin on 4/13/16.
 */

public class HotkeyController
{

    public static void createHotkeys(final String name, final Scene scene)
    {
        final KeyCombination exitCMD = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.E, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (exitCMD.match(event))
                {
                    System.out.println("CTRL + E was pressed on " + name + " display\n" +
                            "Exiting the application");
                    Platform.exit();
                }
            }
        });

        final KeyCombination settingsCMD = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (settingsCMD.match(event))
                {
                    System.out.println("CTRL + S was pressed on " + name + " display\n" +
                            "Opening Settings Scene");
                    /*
                     *  This is where we need to launch a scene for settings
                     */
                    try
                    {
                        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/settingsscreen.fxml"));
                        Stage settingsStage = new Stage();
                        settingsStage.setTitle("FTX Signage Settings");
                        settingsStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500 , 400));
                        settingsStage.show();

//                        SettingsController settingsController = new SettingsController();
//                        GettersSetters getSet = new GettersSetters();
//                        settingsController.getText();
//                        String hostname = getSet.getHostname();
//                        settingsController.setText(hostname);

                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @jewelsea, I edited the post to reflect the exact questions.